# RequestContext udpate via PrimeFaces Selector (PFS)

Tags: primefaces

Is it possible to update components via `RequestContext` with PFS? I have tried `RequestContext.getCurrentContext().update("@(.some-class)");` but seems it does nothing (PF v6.0.18).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO you cannot do that from the server side.  From this announcement: https://www.primefaces.org/search-expression-framework/

> NOTE:
>
> Client side expressions are also NOT safe as server side expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/). It includes [component utils](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Components) which include methods to simplify searching them (compared to using the JSF spec API). It might help you to (more easily) find the components you need to update.